# External RAID enclosure

Tags: raid

I need a solution for file write speeds around 200MB per second.
Data redundancy is not necessary, therefore RAID 0 will probably be used.
Finally, data will be streaming for potentially hours, so SSD's are out of the question.
Is an external RAID enclosure the answer here?

To prevent this from being closed due to openness, you could explain why this solution will/will not work, and point me towards a better alternative if there is one?

A simple "yes" will tell me that this is the solution for me.

Edit: Grammar

Comment: Are the writes random, or are you capturing something nice and sequential?

Comment: They are sequential

Comment: Modern SSDs can handle about the same write level as rotating disks.

Comment: I was concerned with the _amount_ of data being written in regards to the SSD. Multiple TB's worth of SSD storage add$ up quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200MB/s comes to about 703GB/hour, and you said "several hours". So it could be several terabytes before the write session is done. And it's nice an sequential.

Write rates like that are easily handled with rotational media. You'll definitely want a fast connection, so no USB2 and probably not Firewire. 3G SAS or SATA will work, I've seen them handle speeds like that. I'd personally put no fewer than 3 drives in the RAID0 set, but 7.2K RPM drives should be able to handle that kind of write pattern.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just wanted to confirm some thoughts before making a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've decided on disk versus SSD, the only question is where you put them. An external direct attached shelf is indeed an option, as is internal disks if you have enough bays.